# How I do call this function present in plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am using one plugin which in general has code something like:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.makeEditable = function (options) {
        function _fnGetRowIDFromAttribute(row) {
            return "foo";
        }

         return this.each(function () {
             //some code
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

How do I call `_fnGetRowIDFromAttribute` from outside plugin i.e on my page?

Comment: You can't, that's the point of making it part of a plugin-- it's encapsulated and not part of the public return value of the function.

Comment: So any workaround? I have the plugin code. How can I make it a part of public call?

Comment: Make a copy of the function in the global scope. Copy-paste job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your function accessible from the global scope and respect jQuery conventions, you should attatch it in the jQuery object.

```
(function ($) {
    $._fnGetRowIDFromAttribute = function(row) {
        return "foo";
    }

    $.fn.makeEditable = function (options) {
         return this.each(function () {
             //some code
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Or you could put it in a namespace:

```
(function ($) {
    $.myModule = $.myModule || {};
    $.myModule._fnGetRowIDFromAttribute = function(row) {
        return "foo";
    }

    $.fn.makeEditable = function (options) {
         return this.each(function () {
             //some code
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Another remark: if your function does not use anything of the scope of $.fn.makeEditable's, there is no reason to redefine it at each call to $.fn.makeEditable. You can just define it in the immediate function used to specify the jQuery plugin.

Last but not least, a variable or a function with it's name ***starting with underscore*** is a conventional way to tell that it's ***private*** and should not be called from outside. So you should consider changing it's name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it accessible from outside, you need to replace this line:

```
function _fnGetRowIDFromAttribute(row) {
```

with this line:

```
_fnGetRowIDFromAttribute = function(row) {
```

This adds the function in the global scope; you can also define the function outside your module block.